# Where can the last 8 CD pieces be found?

Tags: savant-ascent

I have been playing the game Savant Ascent on PC for 1-2 days now, and I got 4 full CDs from finishing Story and 1 full + 1 piece from Time Attack and Endless combined.

How many CD pieces are in TA and Endless, respectively, and do I have to last longer than 2-3 minutes to get the endless ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Soundtracks
>
> Obtain 6 Soundtracks by collecting all the golden CD pieces scattered across the different game modes
> — [*Savant - Ascent* Achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/259530/achievements/)

This proves that there are 6 CDs in total.
4 of them are collected from parts in Story Mode and 2 in other game modes.

[Savant - Ascent : A Complete Guide of Basically Everything](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=209140774#201990) has more information on this topic:

> #### Endless Mode, The 5th + 6th Powers, and what lies beyond...
>
> In order to obtain the amount of CD Pieces needed for your final two powers, you'll need to survive until the 4th Wyrm Wave

So, apparently, the only other game mode that you need is Endless Mode.
Wyrms are those long dragon-like things, by the way.

The same page states:

> At some point between the 0:40 second - 1:00 minute mark, the first Wyrm will spawn in, *[...]* all subequent Wyrms waves will spawn in roughly a minute after each other.

So it looks like you will need to survive for about 4 minutes to reach the final CD piece.

Comment: Thank you! I was really confused over this... Wait, 4 wyrms!!! Oh my.